# ListPicker issue in WindowsPhone8

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Am using a list picker in a WindowsPhone App,I am not able to load the selected element in the list picker,the selected value shows the first item which was loaded during the page load,But the value we get in selection changed event is the correct one.Plz help me

XAML :

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate  x:Name="picker">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0 0 0 0"  FontSize="25" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}"/>
        </StackPanel>                      
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerFullModeItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0 0 0 0" FontSize="18" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Grid.Resources>

<toolkit:ListPicker ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerFullModeItemTemplate}" FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerFullModeItemTemplate}"  x:Name="list_city" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="list_city_SelectionChanged" Height="170"  Grid.RowSpan="1" Margin="12,12,12,0"   />
```

C# :

```
private void list_city_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int i = list_city.SelectedIndex;
    string val = lst_cities[i];  //list of cities    
}
```

Comment: please clarify your question: what are `lb_countyname` and `lb_city_name` controls - at least they are not in your XAML. Then, where do you want to show selected value(ie in what control) and how you achieve it? Also this line has no sense - `string county = lb_countyname.Text;`...

Comment: @ Nogard the selected value of the listpicker that displayed is not getting changed,but the value am getting in selection changed event is the changed value.I dont know why the selected value in the display is not getting reset.

Comment: `the selected value of the listpicker that displayed is not getting changed` - please provide example for this one. Do you change `selectedvalue` from code or UI? if former you should add to your `ListPicker` the following attribute `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCity, Mode=TwoWay}"` and modify property `SelectedCity` in your ViewModel. If latter - please provide more details

Answer (score 0):

Try this! It might work,

```
private void list_city_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int i = (sender as ListBox).SelectedIndex;
    string val = lst_cities[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the SelectedItem property of the ListBox to a property in your ViewModel using TwoWay databinding. If your property has the correct selected item you want when the ListBox loads then it will have the correct selection.

Comment: As u said I added mode=twoway in textblock in data template,still not working.